# Unfair election results probability

Tags: probability

Folks, last time I've manipulated probabilities was some $30$ years ago so I'm struggling with the following problem:

Suppose we have $N=6000$ candidates for $M=100$ seats in a parliament.
Each candidate has resources $R$. Most of candidates are poor and have $R_P=1000$ USD  each as resources but a fraction $f=2\%$ of candidates are rich have $R_R=10000$ USD  each as resources.
The chances for the given candidate to be elected are linearly proportional to the resources available.

Question $1$: What is the most probable outcome of this election in terms of number of rich and poor elected candidates.

Question $2$: What is the probability to have more than $\frac{M}{2} = 50$ rich candidates elected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine 6000 squares. Those coloured red are the poor, and those blue are the rich. Since the rich are 10 times more likely to win, we multiply the number of blue by 10, giving a total of 7080 squares consisting of 5880 poor and 1200 rich.

Question 1.

In accordance with the [law of large numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers), for a large selection (100 seats) the most likely distribution would match that of the total: so you expect 1200/7080 = 17% to be rich and the remaining 83% poor.

In general, to compute the probability of there being exactly $k$ rich people, you employ the binomial distribution:

$$ P(k)={{100}\choose k}\left(\frac{1200}{7080}\right)^k\left(1-\frac{1200}{7080}\right)^{100-k} $$

Question 2.

Here you apply the [binomial cumulative distribution function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function)

$$ P(>50)=1-P(\leq 50) = 1-\sum_{i=0}^{50} {{100}\choose{i}}\left(\frac{1200}{7080}\right)^i\left(1-\frac{1200}{7080}\right)^{100-i} \sim 10^{-14} $$

in other words, it'll never happen.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great explanation